# When clicking on ajax.actionlink in its oncomplete function I can't update the html of a div whith requested data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In one partial view I've got some ajax.ActionLinks which when clicked update the div 'importpartupdate' (they just updates the div with new ajax.actionLinks with other routevalues). The problem is that when this update is completed I have to update another div - depending on which link is clicked . That's why in my  OnComplete function of my ajax.ActionLink I make an ajax request to the action'GridViewLanguage'  which returns me the partial view which should update this other div with class `.floatLanguage`. So the first time when I click a link everything works correctly and my two  div are correctly updated. But the second time I click a new link it seems like the floatlanguuage div is not updated like somehow the browser is caching the previous info I don't know. I tried with cache:false- nothing worked.

```
     @model  MvcBeaWeb.GroupMenu



<nav class="sidebar-nav">

    <div class="divLeftShowMenu">
        <ul>
            @{
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (MvcBeaDAL.WebServiceBeaMenu item in Model.MenuLeft)
                    {

                      <li>
                        @Ajax.ActionLink(@item.SpecialWord, "ImportShow", new { id = Model.LanguageName, menuID = item.ID, articlegroupID = item.ArticlegroupID, counter = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "importPartUpdate", HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnComplete = "success("+@item.ID+")" }, new { id=item.ID})

                      </li> 
                    }
                } 
            }
        </ul>
    </div> 


</nav>
   <script>
       function success(ids) {

           var nocache = new Date().getTime(); 

           jQuery.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GridLanguageView")/?menuID='+ids


           }).done(function (data)
           {


             $(".floatLanguage").replaceWith(data);
             alert(data);
           });



       }
     </script>
```

Comment: Is success() method being called everytime you click action link?

Comment: yes this is the method which is called everytime

Comment: I think problem with ".floatLanguage" selector. After first time replacing with data, do you still have control with ".floatLanguage" class?. replaceWith will replace entire DOM element itself not content.

Comment: if i say $(".floatLanguage").html(data) - the problem remains

Comment: does data has control with your class name?

Comment: no, the  data which this ajax request returns is just dimple user control with  telerik radgrid control

Comment: If you look in your browser's debugging tools, specifically the network console, is it returning a 304 response code?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that cached data is being served when you click on the link. I had the similar issue when trying to load the partial view content in a jquery dialog upon click of ActionLink.

All I had to do is to send `Date().getTime()` as a Url parameter to always request for new data. `cache:false` will not have an effect here. Try the following

```
function success(ids) {
   var date = new Date();
       $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GridLanguageView")/?menuID='+ids '&'  + date.getTime()
       }).done(function (data)
       {
         $(".floatLanguage").replaceWith(data);
          alert(data);
       });
   }
```

I see that you started with `var nocache = new Date().getTime();` but I don't see that you're using it anywhere.